# Search for a dynamic field in a mongodb collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

If I were to search for a particular field in a mongodb collection my command would look something like this :

```
db.collection.find({ name : "John"})
```

If I want to make the field name dynamic, what would the command be?

Example:

```
db.collection.find({ <Dyanmic field variable> : <Value>})
```

Or is there an alternative to achieve this function?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a field name stored in a variable in your code, e.g. "find all documents where the field whose name is stored in the value of the variable `fieldname` is `22`"? Or you want to search across multiple field names in MongoDB at once, e.g. "find all documents where a field whose name starts with `'duck_'` has the value `44`"?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the variable in place of the dictionary key:

```
name = 'field_name'
db.collection.find({name : "John"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem happens when you try without knowing data type. So in order to handle this , i used the following:

```
def multi_row_single_field_update(self, crieteriafldnm, crieteriafldtyp, updtfldnm, updtfldval, updtfldtyp):
    try:
        criteria = raw_input('\nEnter ' + crieteriafldnm + ' to update\n')
        if crieteriafldtyp == 'int':
            count = self.my_connect.find({str(crieteriafldnm): int(criteria)}).count()
        else:
            count = self.my_connect.find({str(crieteriafldnm): str(criteria)}).count()
        updt_criteria = int(criteria) if updtfldtyp == 'int' else str(criteria)
        self.my_connect.update(
            {"$atomic": 1},
            {str(crieteriafldnm): updt_criteria},
            {"$set": {str(updtfldnm): str(updtfldval)}},
            upsert=False, multi=True
               )
```

Comment: I don't think this is an answer on the question of OP. Try to focus on his need, which would be IMHO creating a dict dynamically and then execute `db.collection.find(dinamically_built_dict)`.